# React. Why when i request api after request appear api in broswer url that i call

Tags: reactjs

Here is exapmle code

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
 axios.get("http://api.example.com/id=1&param1=1")
.then(response => console.log(response));
}
```

And after request is see in browser's url it is http://my.site.com/id=1&param1=1
What to do that avoid this error?

Comment: `axios.get` doesn't change the url. Are you sure there isn't something else responsible for that in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` If this is a submit event on a form, then the default behavior would be to take those parameters from the form elements and do a GET request with them to your current path.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault